CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults" in React Native project
I'm working on a React Native project using Expo and have installed the following dependencies:

"@react-native-firebase/app": "21.6.1"
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "21.6.1"
"@react-native-firebase/database": "21.6.1"

I also have react-native-vision-camera-text-recognition version 3.1.1 installed.
After running expo prebuild and navigating to the ios folder to run pod install, I encounter the following error:

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
"GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults":   In Podfile:     RNFBDatabase (from ../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/database`) was resolved to 21.6.1, which depends on
Firebase/Database (= 11.5.0) was resolved to 11.5.0, which depends on
FirebaseDatabase (~> 11.5.0) was resolved to 11.5.0, which depends on
GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 8.0)
VisionCameraTextRecognition (from `../node_modules/react-native-vision-camera-text-recognition`) was resolved to 3.1.1, which depends on   GoogleMLKit/TextRecognitionChinese was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on     MLKitTextRecognitionChinese (~> 1.0.0-beta1) was resolved to 1.0.0-beta1, which depends on       MLKitCommon (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on         GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.0)

[!] [Codegen] warn: using experimental new codegen integration`
What I've Tried:

Removing the ios folder and rebuilding with expo prebuild.
Running pod install again after rebuilding.
Running pod repo update

I still encounter the same error when I run the pod install command in the ios folder
